Background color of QPlainTextEdit in Qt 6.7
Could anybody explain why in Qt 6.7 background color of QPlainTextEdit is changed from white to some gray?
A following code:
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPlainTextEdit>

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    QApplication app( argc, argv );

    QPlainTextEdit e;
    e.resize( 400, 300 );
    e.show();

    return QApplication::exec();
}

Shows a following window:

And, yeah, I'm on Windows 10. On Linux I still use Qt 6.6.3.
Is it possible to change it back to white?
e.setBackgroundRole( QPalette::Base );

Doesn't change anything.
Thank you.

Possibly related to QTBUG-120633.

Hm, maybe, I thought it's something new :) But it's an issue. OK. Thank you.
